# Prove that a field of a set has $2^r$ elements if it has finite cardinality.

Tags: combinatorics, measure-theory, cardinals

Prove that a field of a set $A$ has $2^r$ elements if it has finite cardinality.

The definition of algebra is given here "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets"

My try: I was trying to start from a simple example. Suppose $F:=\{\phi, X, a_1, a_1^c\}\subseteq A$ where $X$ is the total set.

Now $\exists b_1 \in A\setminus F$ then $b_1^c \in A\setminus F.$ If $ b_1 \subseteq a_1$ then $b_1^c \cup a_1\in A\setminus F$ and $(b_1^c \cup a_1)^c\in A\setminus F.$ From here the proof is getting clumsy. Is there any easy way to prove this?

Comment: For typing less I will call $0$ the $\emptyset$ and $1=X$. If $A=\{0\}$, then $|A|=1=2^0$ we are done. Otherwise, let $x\in A\setminus\{0\}$ minimal. Then for all $y\in A$ either $xy=x$ or $xy=0$. For every $y\in A$ with $xy=0$ we have the map $y\mapsto z=x+y$ to the $z\in A$ such that $zx=x$. This map is injective, since $x+y_1=x+y_2$, implies $y_1y_2=y_2(x+y_1)=y_2(x+y_2)=y_2$ and by symmetry $=y_1$. It is onto since if $zx=x$, then $x+zx^c=zx+zx^c=z(x+x^c)=z1=z$. Therefore, $|A|=2|x+A|$ is even. Apply induction, on the cardinality, since $x+A$ is also a finite field of sets.

Comment: An atom of the field $F$ is a non-empty $f\in F$ such that $f $ is $\subset$-minimal among non-empty members of $F$, that is, if $f\supseteq g\in F$ then $g=f$ or $g=\emptyset$. Let $B$ be the set of atoms of $F$. Then $x\in F$ iff $x=\cup C$ for some $C\subseteq B.$ And any two atoms are disjoint so if $C_1,C_2$ are unequal subsets of $B$ then $\cup C_1\ne \cup C_2.$

Comment: Above I meant $x^cA$ instead of $x+A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: Say that $x \sim y$ if the sets in the algebra that contain $x$ are precisely the one's that contain $y$. This is an equivalence relation. Let $[A_x]$ denote the equivalence class of $x$.  Verify that $x \in A$ for some $A$ in the algebra implies that $[A_x] \subseteq A$. Now show that any set is a union of equivalence classes. It folows now that there is a bijection from the algebra onto the family of subsets of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ where $n$ is the number of equivalence classes.

Comment: Can you just elaborate the 1st line. No more hint. Just the 1st line with an example so that I don't misunderstand.

Comment: In the example  in your attempt $x\sim y$ iff $x$ and $y$ both belong to $a_1$ or they both belong to $a_1^{c}$.

Comment: And what about in general $s \sim y$ iff $x,y \in a$ or $x,y \in a^c$ for some $a \in A$?

Comment: @Ri-Li Since any algebra contains the whole space $\Omega$ you would have $x \sim y$ for all $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

We prove more generally that

> Let $S$ be a finite Boolean algebra. Then $S \cong 2^n$ for some $n$, where $2$ is the 2-element Boolean algebra.

Proof: we proceed by strong induction on $|S|$.

If $|S| \leq 1$, then clearly $|S| = 1 = 2^0$ and we are done.

If $|S| > 1$, then let $f$ be a minimal element of $S \setminus \{0\}$. Such an $f$ exists since $S \setminus \{0\}$ is a finite nonempty partial order.

Consider $\neg f$. Note that $S_1 = \{x \in S \mid x \leq f\}$ and $S_2 = \{x \in S \mid x \leq \neg f\}$ are both Boolean algebras under the inherited order from $S$ (in general, $\{x \in S \mid x \leq w\}$ is a Boolean algebra for all $w$).

Note that $S_1 \cong 2$, since $S_1$ only has two elements, $f$ and $0$.

Furthermore, note that $|S_2| < |S|$, since $f \land \neg f = 0 < f$ and therefore $f \nleq \neg f$. Therefore, by the strong inductive hypothesis, we can take some $n$ such that $S_2 \cong 2^n$.

I claim that $S \cong S_1 \times S_2$ as Boolean algebras. Indeed, the isomorphism is $s \mapsto (s \land f, s \land \neg f)$, and the inverse is $(a, b) \mapsto a \lor b$. It's easy to verify that both directions are Boolean algebra homomorphisms and that they are inverse isomorphisms.

Therefore, $S \cong S_1 \times S_2 \cong 2 \times 2^n \cong 2^{n + 1}$.